# React multiple output files of bundle of single Input file

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am working in React and want to publish my code . I am creating bundle using webpack , since I want the bundle to be divided in three parts , that is  , my code should have divided in to three different files so that not only one file  get populated too much . I went through the official docs of webpack and other online sites but still not found the solution for this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete configuration `webpack.config.js` that you can base yours on.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;

const WebpackConfig = {
  // multiple component entry points
  entry: {
    AppPart1: './src/AppPart1',
    AppPart2: './src/AppPart2',
    AppPart3: './src/AppPart3'
  },

  // generate files
  output: {
    path: './assets',
    // creates JS files like "AppPart1.js"
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  module: {
    preLoaders: [
       // add any pre-loaders here, OPTIONAL
    ],
    loaders: [
       // add any loaders here, like for ES6+ transpiling, React JSX etc
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js']
  },

  plugins: [
    // this will factor out some common code into `bundle.js`
    new CommonsChunkPlugin('bundle.js'),
  ]
};

module.exports = WebpackConfig;
```

At the end of `webpack` build, here is what you will have in the `assets` folder

- `AppPart1.js`
- `AppPart2.js`
- `AppPart3.js`
- `bundle.js`

`bundle.js` will contain some shared code and must be included on all your pages along with the appropriate part file for the page.

Comment: In that case just put one key into `entry`. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: can it be able to produce multiple output files ?

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that it will produce multiple files with the common chunk in `bundle.js`. So you can afford to load only the code that is actually needed for a given page by combining it with another chunk file from the entry points list. If you want a single module to be splitted, that is not an easy problem. The problem definition is just vague.

Comment: In my case there is only one bundle file is creating and I want to split that one , And I have clearly mentioned in the question statement that I want my bundle file to be split in three different parts .

Comment: The only way to do that is to have multiple entry points. You cannot simply take a bundle and split it into 3 parts. By having 3 entry points, you are clearly denoting that these 3 modules form independent parts of the app up to a certain extent.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the three separate files, you can put multiple entry points on your webpack config:

```
entry: {
        "bundle1":"./src/app/somefile1.jsx",
        "bundle2":"./src/app/somefile2.jsx,
        "bundle3":"./src/app/somefile2.jsx"
}
```

Comment: You can only accomplish this by having multiple entry points so you get multiple bundled js files.